# Android sqlite filter query result contains string in other two tables

Tags: sqlite

**UPDATED**

Finally I used this way to get filtered result.

```
SELECT * FROM statuses WHERE _id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT statuses._id FROM statuses, filtered_sources WHERE statuses.source LIKE '%'||filtered_sources.text||'%'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT statuses._id FROM statuses WHERE statuses.screen_name IN(SELECT filtered_users.text FROM filtered_users)
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT statuses._id FROM statuses, filtered_keywords WHERE statuses.text LIKE '%'||filtered_keywords.text||'%'
);
```

**Why I use this way instead of combine results directly?**

I'd like to use `query()` method rather than `rawQuery()` in Android.

@zapi and @sixfeetsix , thank you very much, your answers give me this idea !

**Download sqlite database for test here** http://db.tt/ZsEwE9TV

I have a sqlite database contains three tables : statuses, filtered_keywords, filtered_sources.

Columns in each tables:

statuses:

```
|_id|text|source|
```

filtered_keywords and filtered_sources:

```
|_id|text|
```

now I'd like to filter query results from `statuses` contains words in `filtered_keywords` and `filtered_sources`.

I know I can use `LIKE` in sqlite, but I can't use it like `IN` function.

```sql
SELECT * FROM statuses WHERE text in (SELECT text FROM filtered_sources);
```

So I have to query all data in `filtered_sources` and `filtered_keywords` as `Cursor` first, then build a long where clause, it's really slow.

Is there any simple way to get the filtered result ?

Comment: can u provide some sample tables with text and how the filtering should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT statuses.* 
FROM statuses, filtered_sources
WHERE statuses.text LIKE '%' || filtered_sources.text || '%'
UNION
SELECT statuses.*
FROM statuses, filtered_keywords
WHERE statuses.text LIKE '%' || filtered_keywords.text || '%';';
```

For example:

```
create table statuses (_id, text, source);
create table filtered_keywords (_id, text);
create table filtered_sources (_id, text);

insert into statuses values (1, 'foobar', NULL);
insert into statuses values (2, 'foofoobar', NULL);                              
insert into statuses values (3, 'foofoobarbar', NULL);

insert into filtered_keywords values (1, 'foofoo');
insert into filtered_sources values (1, 'barbar');

.headers on
.mode column
.width 3 15 6 

SELECT statuses.* 
FROM statuses, filtered_sources
WHERE statuses.text LIKE '%' || filtered_sources.text || '%'
UNION
SELECT statuses.*
FROM statuses, filtered_keywords
WHERE statuses.text LIKE '%' || filtered_keywords.text || '%';';
```

outputs:

```
_id  text             source
---  ---------------  ------
2    foofoobar              
3    foofoobarbar
```

**UPDATE**:

I updated the `SELECT` statement as the OP points out that the previous version didn't work when one of the two filtered_* tables is empty.

Comment: I tried in my database, it works, but I found a problem. If one of the table have 0 rows, I will get empty result. Do you have any idea to solute this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: oops misunderstood your intention. It won't work for you.

---

I guess that works:

```
SELECT * FROM statuses WHERE text in (
    SELECT text FROM filtered_sources WHERE text LIKE '%?%'
    UNION
    SELECT text FROM filtered_keywords WHERE text LIKE '%?%'
);
```

that should first query the tables with a `LIKE`, combine both into one set of texts and then select all texts from there with `IN`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using joins for your query:

```
SELECT * FROM statuses JOIN filtered_keywords ON statuses.text = filtered_keyword.text JOIN filtered_sources ON statuses.source = filtered_sources.text
```